# Block size for rsa algorithm?

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption

I read book about cryptography but I don't understand this statement:

> In RSA the block size must be less than or equal to log2(n).

somebody help me

Comment: What is the context here?  What is `n`?

Comment: n prime number look C = Me mod n

M = Cd mod n = (Me)d mod n = Med mod n

Answer (score 1):

The RSA algorithm involves performing a modulo by N (the modulus) operation to recover the plain-text value. As a result, the plain-text must be less than the N, since the modulo operation results in a value between 0 and N-1.

To describe this restriction in terms of a "block size", we need to know the number of bits in N, which is simply log<sub>2</sub>(N).